# How is the iOS and Android Facebook SDKs secure?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I've been rather curious around how Facebook knows that the entity making calls to it, is who they say they are. For example I can inspect an iOS IPA file, get the Facebook app information from info.plist, create a shell app with the same appID in Xcode and start pretending to be the Facebook App in the plist. How would the Facebook secret key come into play as its never used on the app for obvious reasons?

I see that the Android SDK makes use of key hashes. How is this used to secure the SDK?